# Pandas: operations with nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I produce the following using pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(25).reshape((5,5)),index = ['A','B','C','D','E'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(25).reshape((5,5))*2,index = ['A','B','C','D','E'])
df[2] = np.nan
df1[3] = np.nan
df[4] = np.nan
df1[4] = np.nan
df2 = df+df1
print(df2)

     0    1   2   3   4
A  3.0  3.0 NaN NaN NaN
B  3.0  3.0 NaN NaN NaN
C  3.0  3.0 NaN NaN NaN
D  3.0  3.0 NaN NaN NaN
E  3.0  3.0 NaN NaN NaN
```

What do I have to do to get this instead?

```
    0   1   2   3     4
A   3   3   2   1   NaN
B   3   3   2   1   NaN
C   3   3   2   1   NaN
D   3   3   2   1   NaN
E   3   3   2   1   NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fill_value` argument of the [DataFrame.add method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

> fill_value : None or float value, default None Fill missing (NaN)
>   values with this value. If both DataFrame locations are missing, the
>   result will be missing.

```
df.add(df1, fill_value=0)
Out: 
     0    1    2    3   4
A  3.0  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
B  3.0  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
C  3.0  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
D  3.0  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
E  3.0  3.0  2.0  1.0 NaN
```

Comment: The advantages of using the `.add` method over the `+` sign are pretty cool eh?